# MySQLi as an static class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I have the following code that is able to create a class that has a single static instance of the database object, and two static functions for rows and columns.

```
<?php class Database{

    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone(){}

    public static function call(){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){  
            self::$instance = new MySQLi("localhost", "foo", "bar", "fizz");  
            if(self::$instance->connect_error){  
                throw new Exception('Error MySQL: ' . self::$instance->connect_error);  
            }  
        } 
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function getRow($id, $db){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$db." WHERE id=".$id;
        $result = self::call()->query($query);
        return $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
} ?>
```

However, when I call getRow from another class, like this

```
$data = Database::getRow($id, "posts");
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   fetch_assoc() on a non-object in
>   database.php
>   on line 27

And I check it again and again and everything seems to be in order, maybe I have a error in call() ?

Comment: This is not a good idea, it's basically introducing a singleton by the back door.

Comment: @GordonM way to revive an old question, but you're right. I'm better than this now. To begin with, I don't write PHP anymore.

Comment: Wasn't me!  This was already near the top of the PHP questions list, I hadn't noticed the date on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will happen if you have an error in your SQL syntax -- did you check it and make sure there were no errors?

I would have error checking, something like

```
if( self::$instance->error ) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a variable called $db to getRow(), maybe that should be a table?

Answer (score 0):

`query()` will return `false` if the SQL query fails. You can add the following to handle this error:

```
$result = self::call()->query($query)
if($result === false)
    throw new Exception(call()->error); // throw exception, use MySQLi error as message

return $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and it works, you must have an error in the query. What may cause this error is:

1. Check what you pass to `Database::getRow()`. There may be some non-numerical characters in your id
2. Check if column name `'id'` exists, this sounds funny but it happened to me a million times, i was querying column `'id'` instead of `'product_id'` and so on
3. Check if table `$db` exists
4. Make sure you don't switch the function parameters by an accident. `Database::getRow(24, 'people');` instead of `Database::getRow('people', 24);`

I can't think of anything else that may cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getRow($id,$table)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->instance->query($query);
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
if(!isset(self::$instance)){
```

will have sometimes strange behaviours. checking isset() against a null value is subject to failings. try this:

```
private static $instance = null; // it defaults to null but hey, rather be on the sure side
// foo
if (self::$instance === null) {
// mysqli creation foo
```